# How to get the data in the object of the event registered in the _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler function when the application relaunch

Tags: flutter, oop, firebase-cloud-messaging, sip

I am facing issue: When _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler function called, I listen sip event from class ListenRejectCallSip. But when I relaunch app, I can not get field `currCall` in class ListenRejectCallSip. I think new process is running over when my app is restarted then I lost old value call.

In my _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('Background handle called!');
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  helper ??= SIPUAHelper();
  UaSettings settings = UaSettings();
  Map<String, dynamic> mapJsonProfile = json.decode(pref.getString("profile")!);
  Profile profile = Profile.fromJson(mapJsonProfile);
  String ext = profile.extension;
  String password = profile.password;
  String domain = profile.domain;
  String sipProxy = profile.proxy;
  String port = profile.port;
  PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  String appId = packageInfo.packageName;
  settings.webSocketUrl = "wss://$sipProxy:$port/wss";
  final Map<String, String> _wsExtraHeaders = {
    'Origin': 'https://$sipProxy',
    'Host': '$sipProxy:$port'
  };
  String token = "";
  String pnProvider = "fcm";
  token = (await messaging.getToken())!;
  settings.registerParams.extraContactUriParams = <String, String>{
    'pn-provider': pnProvider,
    'pn-param': appId,
    'pn-prid': token
  };
  settings.domain = domain;
  settings.webSocketSettings.extraHeaders = _wsExtraHeaders;
  settings.webSocketSettings.allowBadCertificate = true;
  settings.uri = "sip:$ext@$domain";
  settings.authorizationUser = ext;
  settings.password = password;
  settings.displayName = ext;
  settings.userAgent = 'Mifone Flutter';
  settings.dtmfMode = DtmfMode.RFC2833;
  listenRejectCallSip = ListenRejectCallSip(); // This is class which I want to get value in object initialized
  helper.addSipUaHelperListener(listenRejectCallSip!);
  helper.start(settings);
}
```

My class I want access data when app relauch:

```
class ListenRejectCallSip implements SipUaHelperListener {
  Call? currCall; //This is value I want to get when app relaunch
  @override
  void callStateChanged(Call call, CallState state) {
    print(
        "MESSAGEFROMDARTSIPUA (ListenRejectCallSip): ${state.state}, id_call: ${call.id},ext: ${call.remote_identity}");
    if (state.state == CallStateEnum.PROGRESS) {
      currCall = call;
      // call.hangup({"cause": Causes.BUSY, "status_code": 486});
    } else if (state.state == CallStateEnum.FAILED) {
      helper.unregister(true);
    }
  }

  @override
  void registrationStateChanged(RegistrationState state) {
    print("MESSAGEFROMDARTSIPUA (ListenRejectCallSip): ${state.state}");
    if (state.state == RegistrationStateEnum.UNREGISTERED) {
      helper.removeSipUaHelperListener(this);
    } else if (state.state == RegistrationStateEnum.REGISTERED) {}
  }

  @override
  void onNewMessage(SIPMessageRequest msg) {
    // TODO: implement onNewMessage
  }

  @override
  void onNewNotify(Notify ntf) {
    // TODO: implement onNewNotify
  }

  @override
  void transportStateChanged(TransportState state) {
    // TODO: implement transportStateChanged
  }
}
```

Is there way impossible to get data when app relauch?